# How to convert an approx. 2M character file from UNIX-Format to Windows-Format in PL/SQL?

Tags: windows, oracle, unix, data-conversion

I'm new to PL/SQL and i have to convert a 2M text-file that i get from an other division  of our administration every month.
My Problem is to convert the file from one single Line in UNIX with lots of LF-terminators to almost 1500 smaller lines in DOS/Windows with CR/LF-terminators after each line.

I know that i canot do it with the UTL_FILE tools because my file to convert is longer than 32767 Bytes.

So I decided to use the DBMS_LOB package, but frankly i do not know how to use the Procedures and Funktions in DBMS_LOB for my purpose.

In the past i used Acces-VBA for this task.

Here is my source-code in case anyone of you knows how to code in Acces-VBA and is able to show me how to code this in PL/SQL or at least post to a site with code similar to my code that can solve my problem.

'File conversion from Unix-/Linux-format to DOS/Windows-format and if nessesary opposite too, then the Parameter "treatment" should not be of value "unix2dos".

```
Sub ConvertToWindows(SourceFolder As String, SourceFile As String, TargetFolder As String, TargetFile As String, treatment As Integer, Optional DeleteSource As Boolean)

Dim Contents As String
Dim ReadFile As String
Dim d As Integer

ReadFile = SourceFolder & SourceFile
d = FreeFile

Open ReadFile For Binary As #d
Contents = Space(LOF(d))
Get #d, , Contents
Close #d

Open TargetFolder & TargetFile For Output As #d
If treatment = unix2dos Then         ' check conversion type
    Contents = Replace(Contents, Chr(10), vbCrLf)
Else
    Contents = Inhalt & Chr(10)
End If
Contents = Left(Contents, Len(Contents) - 2)
Print #d, Contents
Close #d

If DeleteSource = True Then
    Kill SourceFolder & SourceFile
End If

End Sub
```

Thanks for helping me.

Comment: There should be many stand-alone tools available which converts line-breaks from Unix to Windows. Why do you like to use PL/SQL?

Comment: Thanks for answering.

I sometimes use Notepad++ for converting.

But the whole process is supposed to run automaticaly every night:

- If vew file is in acertain directory
- convert it from UNIX to Windows
- Generate a.CSV-file
- Imort contents iin some Oracle-Tables
- Perform some action-queries on these tables
- and terminate the preces.

So the conversion is only une part within a procedure/function-chain that runs every night and ist terminated most nights without realy doin anithing, since i don't know in advance when exactly i get new data that have to be imported.